# How to naturally keep bugs away?

Tags: home, pest-control

I hate bugs and do not want them entering my room. I tried various products but none of them performed as expected. There is gotta be a way to naturally, without also damaging me or my items keep the bugs from entering my room. I'd rather not use chemicals, because chemicals usually affect humans in one way or other.

The particular bugs that are bugging me are mosquitoes, moths, bees and other flying types. The bugs are generally getting through windows and doors and I do use a mosquito net but smaller bugs still enter the room.

I live in an apartment on 12th floor. The kitchen is downstairs, and I never eat at my room. However, my building is right next to a forest.

How can I get rid of these bugs, without using chemicals?

Comment: Adding which specific product you've tried, and why you emphasize a "natural" solution ( *what do you have against chemicals?* ) would improve this question. Nice question, regardless! :)

Comment: How are bugs getting in your room?

Comment: What undesirable bugs are entering your room?

Comment: We need to know what type of bugs you're dealing with, because what works for mosquitoes won't work for ants, etc ( cc @ZachSaucier )

Comment: Do you live in an apartment/condo building or a single family home? The thing that will help the most is to keep a clean kitchen. Don't bring food or make a mess of food in any other room than the kitchen. Clean up the kitchen at least once a day if not more. Take the garbage out every night. Put the dishes in the dishwasher every night. Rinse the dishes off when putting them in the sink. If you live in an apartment, then your neighbors could be real dirty and bugs will naturally make their way into your place to no matter how clean. But won't be as bad if you keep the place clean.

Comment: well chemicals usually affect humans in one way or other. the bugs are generally getting through windows and doors and I do have a mosquito net, smaller bugs still enter the room. What bugs? Well ideally every single type but right now the problem is with mosquitoes, moths, bees and other flying types.

Comment: Apartment on 12th floor. Kitchen is downstairs, I never eat at my room. We live right next to a forest.

Comment: The best thing to do, when adding important information, is to [edit] it directly into the question, rather than commenting. That makes the important information a lot more visible and permanent.

Comment: As far as I know citronella is natural... You could try that :)

Comment: how is this not clear? its simple Bugs != NearMe. can you explain what to do with citronella?

Answer (score 6):

You better find a mosquito net which has really tiny holes. I use such a net and have no problems with bugs.

You can also put isolation band on the doors so that all the tiny holes on doors and windows will be closed and there will be no space for the insects to go through. Of course you have to keep your door closed except when you are going in and out.

Another advice from me is to use very thick curtains during the night because the insects are attracted by the light in you room.

Use an electric insects killer. This is not exactly a life hack but will help you kill the flying insects. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Mosquito nets work for us. If they are still getting in then you need new nets with a finer mesh. Make sure there are no holes or gaps.